# Ignore SSL when installing packages in R

Tags: r

When I try to install a package like this: `install.packages("RGtk2")`

I get the following error:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘RGtk2’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2)
Warning in install.packages :
  URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.3/PACKAGES.gz': status was 'SSL connect error'
Warning in install.packages :
  URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.3/PACKAGES': status was 'SSL connect error'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.3:
  cannot download all files
```

How can I disable SSL so that my install goes through? I know that normally this would be bad from a security standpoint, but in this case I'm pretty sure that SSL error happens because there is some corporate proxy server that alters a certificate in some way.

Comment: Do you have the proper version of GTK ( a system package, not an R package) installed? RGtk2 is just an interface to the system package. Notice also that you are using an out-of-date version of R, and for Windoze and Mac users, the default for installation is binary packages, so the first message may be the more important one. Many mirrors do not maintain binaries for old versions of R.

Comment: @42 I have a Mac, how would I check which version of GTK I have? Is there something I can type via the command line?

Comment: The CRAN page for RGtk2 says: `OS X binaries: r-release: not available, r-oldrel: not available`. When I trying to install RGtk2 from source (in R 3.5.1 under High Sierra), I get an error saying it cannot find GTK despite having that Framework installed. Errors reported: "checking for pkg-config... no
checking for INTROSPECTION... no
checking for GTK... no
" ??? Perhaps a missing line in ~/.R/Makevars but I'm not a very sophisticated Unix jockey.

Comment: TL;DR Install via Homebrew: Here's a possibly informative thread from a mirror of R-SIG-MAC: https://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Aorg.r-project+GTK%2B+RGtk2#query:list%3Aorg.r-project%20GTK%2B%20RGtk2+page:1+mid:hnr7xssd2q7qoo5y+state:results